# Predictive Modeling with Influential Events

Tags: regression, predictive-models

I am trying to model the return percentage on debts given the various "static" debt characteristics as well as "dynamic" characteristics.  My definition of "static" characteristics are those that are inherent to the debt and do not change over its life. "Dynamic" characteristics are those that may change over its life (i.e. the debtor makes a payment within 2 months).

For example:
1. Debt is opened. We predict the return percentage at this time based on the debt's inherent "static" characteristics.
2. Debtor makes a payment within 2 months. Our model accounts for this "dynamic" event/characteristic and updates its prediction.

Can regression model the "dynamic" characteristics I describe above?

What is the best way to model this system?

Comment: I think a quick answer to your question is: simple regression can include predictors which are 'dynamic'. However, in its simplest form, you'll need to build a regression model for each moment you'd want to make a prediction, while selecting the data and predictors accordingly. E.g. for the 1st of your two examples, you'll need a model based on all data with 'static' predictors only, but when building your 2months model, you'll need to redefine the population to who-ever has 2months of follow-up and add the relevant 'dynamic' predictors. Similarly a prediction at 4 months repeats this process.

Comment: Thanks IWS. Wouldn't changing the population and including the dynamic predictors be redundant?